# How to create rectangles on canvas as in a graph (picture)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

Can you please tell me how to implement such a graph as in the example?
I have the following test data:

```
[
{
  day: 2,
  sum: 7799857
},
{
  day: 3,
  sum: 6986099      
},
{
  day: 4,
  sum: 6471975,
},
{
  day: 7,
  sum: 5895399,
},
{
  day: 8,
  sum: 5194120,
},
{
  day: 9,
  sum: 4851008,
},
{
  day: 10,
  sum: 4483119,
},
{
  day: 11,
  sum: 3492771,
},
{
  day: 14,
  sum: 2717263,
},
{
  day: 15,
  sum: 1763884,
},
{
  day: 16,
  sum: 1111772,
},
{
  day: 17,
  sum: 148788,
},
...
];
```

I don’t really understand how to separate them (as in the graph, different rectangles)

The chart looks like this
[image]

I'll be glad for a hint.

Comment: If it's possible to use svg instead of canvas, lookup https://d3js.org/  It's a simple library for making graphs using svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be really hard for you to make this using canvas. I would suggest using some library like `chart-js` which operates on canvas.

I tried to do something with canvas for you, but it seems like your data is not related to the picture you added or there is some algorithm that sum the `sum`s that you didn't provide.

Edit:

Fixed with the data you provided. Dimensions are the same, but I'm not sure if this ratio is really calculated or is it just an accident that the first one is a square.

```js
const data = [{
  day: 22,
  sum: 170.23,
}, {
  day: 36,
  sum: 92.96,
}, {
  day: 40,
  sum: 60.01,
}, {
  day: 48,
  sum: 46.41,
}, ];

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

const ratio = data[0].day / data[0].sum;
let lastDay = 0
const scale = 10

for (const item of data) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  const width = (item.day - lastDay) * scale;
  const height = item.sum * ratio * scale;
  ctx.fillRect(lastDay * scale, canvas.height - height, width, height)
  ctx.strokeRect(lastDay * scale, canvas.height - height, width, height)
  lastDay = item.day;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And if I have exactly such data(below is an example), how can I then correlate the proportions as in the figure? Is it possible? (in terms of width, height of axis labels)

`[{day:22,sum: 170.23,},{day:36,sum:92.96,},{day:40,sum: 60.01,},{day:48,sum:46.41,},];`

Comment: How to draw such lines? I understand that you need to use moveTo and lineTo here, but how to correctly specify the coordinates for the intersecting lines here, as in the picture